# Regex : Extracting variables from a string like /var1/var2/var3/

Tags: regex, apache-flex, url, actionscript

I need to extract in actionscript the variables from a string like `/var1/var2/var3/...`

Each variables can be characters or/and number and variable size.

My current regex `/(\w+)/g` work for the first variable but not for the others.

`var matchExpression:RegExp = /(\w+)/g;

var match:Array = matchExpression.exec(browserManager.fragment);`

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regular expressions are not ideal for this. Why not use [String.split()](http://www.adobe.com/support/flash/action_scripts/actionscript_dictionary/actionscript_dictionary696.html)?

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to recommend [Expresso 3.0](http://www.ultrapico.com/Expresso.htm) here - very easy to use and build up strings with.

Do you have a larger or better string example? i.e. will it always be varx\varx\myvarx?

/(\w+)/g doesn't seem to be working on my machine - you sure this works?

Comment: Is there something like that for Mac?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this: `(?<=/)(\w+)(?=/)`

Comment: Your RegEx doesn't work if the variable names don't contain numerics.

Comment: Agree with Chase Seibert, Split() will be better.

Comment: to Daniel May: are you sure? :)

Comment: D'oh! My bad! I didn't place "/"s before and after. :)

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Chase!

The solution :

`var match:Array = browserManager.fragment.split("/");`